# `struct.unpack_from` doesn't work with `bytearray`?

Tags: python, binary-data

Unpacking from strings works:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('>h', 'ab')
(24930,)
>>> struct.unpack_from('>h', 'zabx', 1)
(24930,)
```

but if its a `bytearray`:

```
>>> struct.unpack_from('>h', bytearray('zabx'), 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-4-d58338aafb82>", line 1, in <module>
    struct.unpack_from('>h', bytearray('zabx'), 1)
TypeError: unpack_from() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not bytearray
```

Which seems a little odd.  What am I actually supposed to do about it?  obviously I could:

```
>>> struct.unpack_from('>h', str(bytearray('zabx')), 1)
(24930,)
```

But i'm explicitly trying to *avoid* copying possibly large amounts of memory around.

Comment: You can use the buffer type to refer to the string without taking up more memory, then pass that as an argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like `buffer()` is the solution:

```
>>> struct.unpack_from('>h', buffer(bytearray('zabx')), 1)
(24930,)
```

`buffer()` is not a copy of the original, its a view:

```
>>> b0 = bytearray('xaby')
>>> b1 = buffer(b0)
>>> b1
<read-only buffer for ...>
>>> b1[1:3]
'ab'
>>> b0[1:3] = 'nu'
>>> b1[1:3]
'nu'
```

Alternitively, You(I?) can just use python 3; the limitation is lifted:

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Jun  8 2012, 05:36:09) 
[GCC 4.7.0 20120507 (Red Hat 4.7.0-5)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack_from('>h', b'xaby', 1)
(24930,)
>>> struct.unpack_from('>h', bytearray(b'xaby'), 1)
(24930,)
>>>
```

Comment: Why not just use `buffer('xaby', index, length)`? That doesn't use up extra memory either.

Comment: it happens that the `struct` bit is wrapping around a `bytearray`, chosen *because* it is mutable.  Each time rather than maintain the read-only view of the primary, mutable data, I'd rather just recreate the bits in the middle to get the data from its primary source.  This also goes for just keeping `(24930,)`.  I really do want to unpack from a `bytearray`.

Comment: @Asad: I suspect creating a `buffer` object consumes at least a little memory.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy I see now; wasn't really paying attention to the bytearray modification in the last few lines.